# webdriver working in other files but not the one I need

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have a problem with Selenium and chromedriver.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, google-chrome 98.0.4758.80 and chromedriver 98.0.4758.80.

I am trying to run this code:

```
import time
import random
import requests
import os
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager as CM

# [...other code...]

# set the standard options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Enable Chrome to be controlled by automated test software
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        
# avoiding detection
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

# Default User Profile
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome/default")
    
# set path to chromedriver binary
s = Service(r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
# initialize the bot
bot = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

bot.set_window_size(900, 1000)
    
# hide automation
bot.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
        
# navigate to the website
bot.get('https://website-link')
```

As it is (I believe) correct when I run it in a jupyter-notebook or in a normal python file and then execute it via terminal I don't have any problems. Code works.

The problem emerges when I run it in a specific python file (the one I need for my project). When I do so I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 285, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 113, in <module>
    uploader(row[2], video_name)
  File "/home/my_user/Projects/myfile.py", line 72, in uploader
    bot = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 422, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 421, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 443, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 285, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I thought that maybe the problem was something else in the file, but the only stuff before line 72 (the one that causes this error) has nothing to do with selenium or chromedriver.

EDIT: 'Line 72' (the one referenced in the error traceback) is:

```
bot = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

What can it be?

UPDATE:
The code runs if I comment out the following line:

```
# options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome/default")
```

It worked in jupyter with it tho. Maybe it has something to do with my data directory.
I will investigate further as I have seen similar problems in a couple of forums without any answers.

Comment: As you said it doesn't look to have anything to do with selenium or chromedriver, so include the code that makes the requests... you're getting an incomplete response from the server for some reason.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks! How do I do that? Sorry if it's such a stupid question, but it's my first project using Selenium and Chromedriver. I'm learning. I have added the specific line that causes the error.

Comment: don't think that's the line... you're making an http-request somewhere... using urllib?

Comment: @pcalkins yea that's the line. I have no clue why it's saying all that stuff, but apparently it has to do with my user-data-dir.

Comment: You're not reading the exception correctly.... that's the 2nd exception.  The first one comes from an http-request somewhere in your other code.  You need to include that code in your post.

Comment: @pcalkins I am not making any requests other than bot.get('...'). I tried passing another directory in options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome/default") and it sort of works (the website knows it's been controlled by an automated software, something that doesn't happen with jupyer)

Comment: I'm guessing "requests" import has a namespace issue with your import as "Service".  Try changing that to "ChromeService" and see if it helps.

Comment: @pcalkins nope. I am importing Service from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service. I also tried to import it as ChromeService but it won't take it. The new directory I made for --user-data-dir stopped working. Creating a new one fixed it. I seriously have no clue as of what's happening

Comment: If you aren't making any requests outside of Selenium, I would check connection to localhost.  I think that's where chromedriver will be receiving and sending back commands.

Comment: the more I think on this, it really seems like a namespace issue.  I'd get rid of all unused imports.  For instance, you don't seem to be using Chromedrivermanager or Requests.  These could use classes that clash with other namespaces...